# javascript match two arrays then display max value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to match two values in two arrays

```
var months ['jan', 'feb', 'march'];
var noDays ['31', '28', '31'];
```

Then i want to fin the months with the maximum number and return them as such

"both jan and march have a total of 31 days"

any suggestions please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that problem could be solved with a simple algorithm:

```
var months = ['jan', 'feb', 'march'];
var noDays = [31, 28, 31];

var maxDays = 0;
var longestMonths = [];
for (var i = 0; i<Math.min(months.length, noDays.length);i++){
   if(noDays[i]>maxDays){
       maxDays = noDays[i];
       longestMonths = [months[i]];
   }else if(noDays[i]==maxDays)
       longestMonths.push(months[i]);
}
```

After executing this code, maxDays is `31`and longestMonths is `['jan', 'march']`